# Converting a series of dates on calendar was failure on my query

Tags: sql, oracle

I run this query to transform my calendar from GREGORIAN to PERSIAN date mode.
it's successfully ok but on a particular day in Persian mode that the month has 31 days, it can't convert it to Persian mode cause of "ORA-01839".

This will happen that I know the date of the Persian model is perfectly correct.

In this sample, the second month of the Persian calendar has 31 days. but when I change day between (19,20,21), Oracle raises an error with "ORA-01839"

--Successfully execute

```
SELECT TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(CAST(SUBSTR('18-MAY-18', 1, 10) AS DATE),
                       'YYYYMMDD',
                       'NLS_CALENDAR=PERSIAN'),
               'YYYYMMDD') date_inventory
  FROM DUAL W;
```

--raise error ORA-01839

```
SELECT TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(CAST(SUBSTR('19-MAY-18', 1, 10) AS DATE),
                       'YYYYMMDD',
                       'NLS_CALENDAR=PERSIAN'),
               'YYYYMMDD') date_inventory
  FROM DUAL W;
```

In the following month, I have the above error. please note that this problem just only for the 2018 year and the other years were different.

```
MAY (19,20,21)
JUL (22)
AUG(21)
SEP(22)
```

I use below query to calculate an inventory process and I can't change it

```
create table TREND_WAREHOUSE
(
  id           NUMBER(30) not null,
  reg_date     NUMBER(30),
  org_id       NUMBER(30),
  goods_id     NUMBER(30),
  qty          NUMBER(30),
  reg_datetime TIMESTAMP(6)
)
insert into TREND_WAREHOUSE (id, reg_date, org_id, goods_id, qty, reg_datetime)
values (1, 13970631, 10, 1, 100, to_timestamp('22-09-2018 00:00:00.000000', 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss.ff'));
insert into TREND_WAREHOUSE (id, reg_date, org_id, goods_id, qty, reg_datetime)
values (2, 13930609, 10, 1, 20, to_timestamp('31-08-2014 14:03:44.689000', 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss.ff'));
insert into TREND_WAREHOUSE (id, reg_date, org_id, goods_id, qty, reg_datetime)
values (3, 13940902, 10, 1, -20, to_timestamp('23-11-2015 00:00:00.000000', 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss.ff'));
insert into TREND_WAREHOUSE (id, reg_date, org_id, goods_id, qty, reg_datetime)
values (4, 13940902, 10, 1, 100, to_timestamp('23-11-2015 00:00:00.000000', 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss.ff'));
insert into TREND_WAREHOUSE (id, reg_date, org_id, goods_id, qty, reg_datetime)
values (5, 13940902, 10, 1, 300, to_timestamp('23-11-2015 00:00:00.000000', 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss.ff'));
commit;


    WITH date_inventory_range AS
     (SELECT TRUNC(MIN(date_inventory), 'MONTH') AS first_date_inventory,
             ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(MAX(date_inventory), 'MONTH'), 1) - 1 AS last_date_inventory

        FROM (SELECT W.ORG_ID,
                     W.GOODS_ID,
                     TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(CAST(SUBSTR(W.REG_DATETIME, 1, 10) AS DATE),
                                     'YYYYMMDD',
                                     'NLS_CALENDAR=PERSIAN'),
                             'YYYYMMDD') date_inventory,
                     SUM(W.QTY) amount
                FROM TREND_WAREHOUSE W
               GROUP BY W.ORG_ID,
                        W.GOODS_ID,
                        CAST(SUBSTR(W.REG_DATETIME, 1, 10) AS DATE)
               ORDER BY 3)),
    all_dates AS
     (SELECT first_date_inventory + LEVEL - 1 AS date_inventory
        FROM date_inventory_range
      CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 1 + last_date_inventory - first_date_inventory),
    dense_data AS
     (SELECT s.org_id,
             s.goods_id,
             TRUNC(d.date_inventory, 'MONTH') AS mnth,
             NVL(SUM(s.amount) OVER(PARTITION BY s.org_id,
                      s.goods_id ORDER BY d.date_inventory),
                 0) AS total_amount
        FROM all_dates d
        LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT W.ORG_ID,
                               W.GOODS_ID,
                               TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(CAST(SUBSTR(W.REG_DATETIME, 1, 10) AS DATE),
                                     'YYYYMMDD',
                                     'NLS_CALENDAR=PERSIAN'),
                             'YYYYMMDD') date_inventory,
                               SUM(W.QTY) amount
                          FROM TREND_WAREHOUSE W
                         WHERE W.Org_Id = 10
                           and W.Goods_Id = 1
                         GROUP BY W.ORG_ID,
                                  W.GOODS_ID,
                                  CAST(SUBSTR(W.REG_DATETIME, 1, 10) AS DATE)
                         ORDER BY 3) s PARTITION BY(s.org_id, s.goods_id)
          ON s.date_inventory = d.date_inventory)
    SELECT org_id,
           goods_id,
           TO_CHAR(mnth, 'YYYY-MM') AS month,
           AVG(total_amount) AS month_avg
      FROM dense_data
     GROUP BY org_id, goods_id, mnth
     ORDER BY org_id, goods_id, mnth;
```

hank for your guidance

Comment: Where are the persian dates? In the numeric column reg_date? Then why is that column not in your query?

Answer (score 1):

Not familiar with :CAST(SUBSTR('19-MAY-18', 1, 10) AS DATE) as I'm used to the to_date function and always specifying a format string.

This seems to work alright:

```
select to_char(to_date('20190521', 'YYYYMMDD'), 'YYYYMMDD', 'NLS_CALENDAR=PERSIAN')
  from dual;
```

Where it goes wrong is converting this string back to date without specifying the NLS_CALENDAR format. So you should use this:

```
select to_date(to_char(to_date('20190521', 'YYYYMMDD'), 'YYYYMMDD', 'NLS_CALENDAR=PERSIAN')
              ,'YYYYMMDD'
              ,'NLS_CALENDAR=PERSIAN')
  from dual;
```

Where you end up with the exact same date you started with.

Please note that an Oracle date does not have a format. It represents a point in time without any specific notation. It's only when converting a date to a string that the format becomes relevant.

Comment: Rene, I add my main query to my question. I use date conversion to the above query and can't change it. because my calculation goes wrong. what do you suggest?

Comment: reg_datetime is a timestamp use CAST(reg_datetime AS DATE) to use it as date. Not sure where the persian comes in.